# Java Collections.sort() missing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I stumbled over this odd bug. Seems like `Collections.sort()` does not modify the sorted list in a way that enables a detection of concurrent modifications when also iterating over the same list. Example code:

```
    List<Integer> my_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    my_list.add(2);
    my_list.add(1);

    for (Integer num : my_list) {

        /*
         * print list
         */
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer i : my_list)
            sb.append(i).append(",");
        System.out.println("List: " + sb.toString());

        /*
         * sort list
         */
        System.out.println("CurrentElement: " + num);
        Collections.sort(my_list);
    }
```

outputs

```
List: 2,1,
CurrentElement: 2
List: 1,2,
CurrentElement: 2
```

One would expect a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but it is not being raised and the code works although it shouldn't.

Comment: You don't have two threads; there's no concurrency (which is *really* what that exception was meant to guard). Even then ... *Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.*

Comment: well you do get that Exception if you add an element to the list (in the same thread). It does not make sense to me why one would adding elements to the list an illegal operation, but chaning the list is not...

Comment: Because it isn't *structurally modifying* the `List`, the nodes that make up the list are all still there and they haven't even changed order. Your iterator isn't affected by a value(s) contained in the nodes changing. In short, it's  really not meant to protect you from yourself.

Comment: The behavior you describe is implementation-specific. You should indicate the JRE you were using (probably Java 6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: This answer was written for Java 6. With [JDK 8u20's Collection.sort now deferring to List.sort](https://medium.com/@edouard.kaiser/collections-sort-the-java8u20-modification-d6a9acf96861), Java 8+ now *does* throw an exception, although as pointed out by Brian Roach, it still doesn't provide any guarantee to that effect.**

Why would it throw `ConcurrentModificationException` when you are not adding/removing elements from your collection while iterating?

Note that `ConcurrentModificationException` would only occur when a new element is added in to your collection or remove from your collection while iterating. i.e., when your Collection is Structurally modified.

> (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list,
> or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress
> may yield incorrect results.)

sort wouldn't structurally modify your Collection, all it does is modify the order.
Below code would throw `ConcurrentModificationException` as it add's an extra element into the collection while iterating.

```
for(Integer num : my_list) {
    my_list.add(12);
    }
```

If you look at the source of the `sort` method in the [Collections](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#L153) class, it's not throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`.

> This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the
> array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the
> corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n2 log(n)
> performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in
> place.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
        Object[] a = list.toArray();
        Arrays.sort(a);
        ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
        for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
            i.next();
            i.set((T)a[j]);
        }
    }
```

### Extract from the book [java Generics and Collections](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do):

> The policy of the iterators for the Java 2 collections is to fail
> fast, as described in Section 11.1: every time they access the backing
> collection, they check it for structural modification (which, in
> general, means that elements have been added or removed from the
> collection). If they detect structural modification, they fail
> immediately, throwing ConcurrentModificationException rather than
> continuing to attempt to iterate over the modified collection with
> unpredictable results.

Comment: +1 - you can also point to the docs for `Collections.sort()` that state *This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array*

Comment: I know. I checked that code too. Still I find that there SHOULD be such a flag being set in `sort()`.

Comment: fair point. so it the famous "it's a feature, not a bug". One way to solve it... :-) Still I don't really see how adding is considered a structural change while mixing up its contents is not.

Comment: @Daniel check here in the arraylist source for what **Structurally modified** means in the code prespective. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of functionality I don't see why it should not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. But according to documentation the iterator throws the exception when it notices structural modification and structural modification is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#modCount) as:

> Structural modifications are those that change the size of the list,
>   or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress
>   may yield incorrect results.

I think there is an argument for claiming that `sort` rearranging the elements causes the iterator to yield wrong results, but I haven't checked what are right results for iterator defined to be.

Speaking of implementation, it is easy to see why it does not: See the source for [ArrayList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) and [Collections](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html):

- `ArrayList.modCount` changes with the so called structural modifications
- `ListItr` methods make a copy of its value in `init` and check that it hasn't changed in its methods
- `Collections.sort` calls `ListItr.set` which calls `ArratList.set`. This last method does not increment `modCount`

So `ListItr.next()` sees the same `modCount` and no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

For Android, it depends on API versions. From API 26, `Collections#sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)` actually calls `List#sort(Comparator<? super E>)`. So, if you sort `ArrayList`, you can get **ConcurrentModificationException** depending on whether you've modified the list in another thread. Here's the source code from `java/util/ArrayList.java` that throws the exception:

```
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    final int expectedModCount = modCount;
    Arrays.sort((E[]) elementData, 0, size, c);
    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
    modCount++;
}
```